# wait for webrequest to finish

Tags: asp.net

hi this function downloads an image from source and adds it to a zip file.
the problem is sometimes the image comes out all messed up(1/3 is downloaded, the rest is empty space) as if the download isn't finish. how can i make sure the download is finished before i move on? thank you.

edit: i have timeout there so it wouldnt wait indefinitely. should i just extend the timeout? or is there a better way?

```
public void addImage(string source, string destination)
    {
        if (isFinalized)
            return;

        try
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(source);
            req.Timeout = 5000;

            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            BufferedStream reader = new BufferedStream(resp.GetResponseStream());

            byte[] fileData = new byte[resp.ContentLength];
            reader.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            zip.AddEntry(destination, fileData);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of the try/catch, for starters. How do you know you're not seeing exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code you need to check the readed bytes and see if you have fully get your image.

```
int FinalRead = reader.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
bool fImageIsOk = FinalRead == resp.ContentLength ;
```

Also I strongly suggest to warp the `BufferedStream` with `using`

I think that the sample code on [msdn have a good example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx).

The part that you must focus is this. Do not try to get at ones your buffer. At the end you can check if you full have get your photo or not. You can also check if the other part is still connected on the process `IsClientConnected`

```
int numBytesToRead = receivedData.Length;

while (numBytesToRead > 0)
{
    // Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
    int n = bufStream.Read(receivedData,0, receivedData.Length);
    // The end of the file is reached.
    if (n == 0)
        break;
    bytesReceived += n;
    numBytesToRead -= n;
}
```